# What to do about upgrading "main" cluster from 8.4 to 9.1 when a 9.1 "main" already exists?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, ubuntu

I have an existing 8.4 cluster (named `main`) that I want to upgrade to 9.1.  However, when I go to upgrade it, I get an error because 9.1 already has a cluster named `main` (apparently a default cluster that is created when I did a `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis`):

```
$ pg_upgradecluster 8.4 main
Error: target cluster 9.1/main already exists
```

What should I do?
Remove the default 9.1/main cluster?  How?
Rename the 9.1/main cluster?  How?

Is there anything special about the Postgresql default `main` cluster?

Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric, Postgresql 8.4.8 and 9.1.4

Update: I just found this [AskUbuntu question-and-answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66194/how-do-i-migrate-my-postgres-data-from-8-4-to-9-1) that says to first do a `pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main`  I tried that and it worked.  So now I'm wondering if there's any data, configuration settings, etc. in the default 9.1 `main` cluster that I might be losing by dropping it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the existing `main` is the default cluster that was created with your installation you can just drop it. Use the tool provided by your installation:

```sh
pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main
```

More info: `man pg_dropcluster`

There is nothing special about the `main` cluster. It's just a cluster like any other which happens to be the default in your installation.

If you haven't worked with the cluster yet, there is nothing in there, that you would lose. But check with psql or pgAdmin (or a client of your choosing) to make sure.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin_Brandstetter!  Another excellent answer from you, I sure appreciate it.